# Spring Security The proper way to Unit test @PreFilter and @PostFilter

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

What id the proper way to Unit Test the Spring Security annotations `@PostFilter` and `@PreFilter`.
I use these annotations in my DAO Class like this:

**TodoDao.java**

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TodoDao implements ITodoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Override
    @PostFilter("filterObject.userByUserId == @authenticationFacade.getAuthenticatedFacade()")
    public List<Todo> getTodosByUserId(int userId) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Todo where userId = ?").setParameter(0, userId).list();
    }
}
```

This is my AuthenticationFacade class:

**AuthenticationFacade.java**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFacade implements IAuthenticationFacade {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao IUserDao;

    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    public User getAuthenticatedFacade() {
        Authentication authentication = getAuthentication();
        User user = IUserDao.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        return user;
    }
}
```

And This my DAO Unit Test class, I use H2 in-memory database:

**TodoDaoTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (value = "classpath:/conf/applicationContext-test.xml")
@Transactional
public class TodoDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory testSessionFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    TodoDao todoDao;

    private boolean mockInitialized = false;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        if(!mockInitialized) {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockInitialized = true;
        }
        todoDao.setSessionFactory(testSessionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser (username = "user", roles = "ROLE_USER")
    //I want to test here if @WithMokUser is different from userId 
    //Than the list sould return empty always.
    public void getTodosByUserIdShouldReturnEmptyListIfCurrentUserIsDifferentFromSearchedUser(){
        int userId = 3;
        assertTrue(todoDao.getTodosByUserId(userId).isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: `@InjectMocks` is useless here, use `@Autowired`. As also mentioned in your other question(s)...

Comment: first, you need to run this test with `WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener` to make Spring Test inject special "user" into security context